# Short way to keep all fields in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, create-table

In MySQL I'm creating a table `ts2` from another table `ts1` by only keeping the distinct rows with the following command

```
CREATE TABLE ts2 AS SELECT DISTINCT 
name, date_of_birth, position, email, ... FROM ts1;
```

Is there a short way to indicate that I want to pick all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator:

```
CREATE TABLE ts2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ts1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

If you just want the data, use `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT DISTINCT *`, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ts2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ts1;
```

If you want the indexes as well, do two queries:

```
CREATE TABLE ts2 LIKE ts1;
INSERT INTO ts2 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ts1;
```